# Can you use Power Attack with Weapon Finesse?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

On the surface, the two feats seem like they should be mutually exclusive, but I couldn't find anything saying they were.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In D&D 3.5e, which Pathfinder is based on, [Power Attack had this line](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#powerAttack):

> You can’t add the bonus from Power Attack to the damage dealt with a light weapon (except with unarmed strikes or natural weapon attacks), even though the penalty on attack rolls still applies.

You could (and still can in Pathfinder) use Weapon Finesse on some non-light weapons, but this covered most of the finesse-able weapons. And remember, even when using Weapon Finesse, your melee attack damage is still Strength-based, so it’s not so unreasonable to say that a faster, more forceful, “wild” attack would do more damage, particularly with a somewhat bigger weapon.

But either way, the Pathfinder version of the feat does not have this line, instead it says

> This bonus to damage is halved (–50%) if you are making an attack with an off-hand weapon or secondary natural weapon.

which wasn’t a thing in the 3.5e version.

Those aren’t the only differences, but since Paizo specifically took the time to rewrite Power Attack, it is likely that the removal of the prohibition on light weapons receiving the damage bonus was intentional.

Also, please note the existence of [Piranha Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/piranha-strike-combat/), which is basically the Dex-based version of Power Attack. Unlike Power Attack, it cannot receive more bonus damage when used with a two-handed weapon, but you get to skip the Strength requirement on Power Attack.

Answer (score 4):

In Pathfinder, there is no restriction on combining these two feats.

You may be remembering a rule from 3.5, where the [Power Attack feat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#powerAttack) could not be used with Light weapons, and Light weapons are the default set that can be used with Finesse. However, this rule was not carried over into Pathfinder. In fact, Pathfinder has several weapons that are explicitly usable with finesse, and not light, such as the [Elven Curve Blade](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/curve-blade-elven/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiP99v7zsfZAhWBHpQKHYyhBfUQFggEMAA&client=internal-uds-cse&cx=006680642033474972217:6zo0hx_wle8&usg=AOvVaw2tSEgsFxpQrEwvLFWFM-7T).